# How to install mod_perl for Bugzilla?

Tags: bugzilla, mod-perl

I wish to install Bugzilla on windows machine , and I don't want to install it using the ready installer , I want to install it in my mysql server and my apache web server

I have installed perl 5, apache 2 and mysql 5.5 but while I was reading the Guide I found that I have to install something called mod_perl.

What is mod_perl and how do I install mod_perl?

Comment: Please improve your English. Also this belongs to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Bugzilla on Windows, you can follow one of the tutorials that are out there.  They walk you through step by step.  This should solve this issue and any further issues.  Here are a couple examples:

http://www.theprogrammersweblog.com/2009/02/installing-bugzilla-on-windows-system.html

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install

For the installation of mod_perl, you can do the same thing (search for tutorials).  Here is one:

http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html

With that being said, this post should really be over at ServerFault.

Comment: Please assume that the OP isn't lazy and he at least read the Mozilla wiki. At best it's not useful to provide such links. At worst it's annoying and unwelcoming for newcomers.

Comment: @the_drow - I wasn't trying to be annoying or unwelcoming.  I apologize if it seemed that way.  It is just that the OP asked "what is mod_perl and how do I install mod_perl" so I assumed that a basic Google search wasn't done.  I thought this was a nicer way of saying "Google it" by providing good answers while saying that a search would find the information for you.

Comment: We do not encourage laziness (and due to that we tend to not answer about homework questions, unless they are interesting or if there is no way that the OP could answer on his own). Thus, if the answer you want to provide is only from google or wikipedia please don't post it. If you have anything further to add or you'd like to summarize the links, provide the relevant clauses/pages in the links you provided or provide any useful insight on the documents themselves, do post. Stackoverflow should have meaningful content. See meta.stackoverflow.com for more details about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

mod_perl brings together Apache and Perl, it allows the two to work together.
[Here is a guide](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html) on how to install it.